# Calculate Confidence interval values and plot the curves accordingly

Tags: javascript, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I have [x,y] pair of data that I am plotting. I am computing the best fit line for the curve using the least-square regression model and predicting the y-values accordingly.

I now want to generate the 95% confidence interval values and plot that as well. If someone could assist me with the formula for calculating the y-values for the confidence band, it will be great. I did try googling before posting here. But, most of the sites assumed, I had some data already. It will also be helpful, if you could direct me to some good links.

Thanks in advance, S.

Comment: Can you clarify further what you mean by "most of the sites assumed, I had some data already"? Surely you need data to draw a best fit line?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statistics given from the regression output should include a "standard error" a 95% confidence interval is the estimate produced by your regression +- 2 of those standard errors google is full of such examples for linear regressions, but it works well for higher degree curves as well.  Here is an example of such a site:

http://stattrek.com/ap-statistics-4/estimate-slope.aspx